# zend framework $this->url is not working correctly

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am having a link to go to update screen and in the update screen a back button to load the index.

**current url is ** http://sample.com/demoZend/public/index/ when i click a post, i take it to this URL,  http://sample.com/demoZend/public/index/update/id/1

now there is a button in this view to go back to **index**.

```
<?php
$this->title = "Update post";
$this->headTitle('Update Post');

echo $this->form;
?>
<a href="<?php echo $this->url(array('controller'=>'index', 'action'=>'index')); ?>">Go Back</a>
```

the problem is, when back button is clicked it goes here, http://sample.com/demoZend/public/index/index/id/1 instead of http://sample.com/demoZend/public/index/index/

**This param id is still remaining. id/1** how this param can be removed and make the url to be **public/index/index/**

I am newbie to zend framework. so this must be a tiny thing for someone who work with zend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Reset Parameter on the Url Helper, to reset all params

`function url(array $urlOptions = array(), $name = null, $reset = false, $encode = true)`

`echo $this->url(array('controller'=>'index', 'action'=>'index'), null, true);`

Comment: please take a look out this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20475079/update-a-record-through-model-in-zend-framework